# Is there a name for this method of displaying UI Icons on a website? How is it done?

Tags: css, image-manipulation, css-sprites

I will take the example of stack**overflow** itself:

Stack**overflow** displays icons using a single image (see image below):

> - What is this method of displaying icons called?
> - How is it done?

[image: sprites.png]

Comment: I would like to point out that the image you posted is called `sprites.png`. This might help direct your research into this topic.

Comment: It´s a way to reduce the number of HTTP-Requests.

Comment: @murgatroid99 tats what I was looking for :).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

css sprites

http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

basically it uses css to pick which part of the image to display. it saves on round trips for fetching the images.

that link gets into the details on how it works.